# Magnific Popup add attribute data-pin-no-hover="true" to the images

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I want to add data-pin-no-hover="true" (pinterest) to the img container from Magnific Popup since the pinterest widget doesn't work on a android tablet

This is my code

```
/**
* jQuery Magnific Popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)
**/
$('.open-gallery-link').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('.mfp-container img').attr('data-pin-no-hover', 'true');
var items = [];
  $($(this).attr('href')).find('a').each(function() {
  items.push( {
      src: $(this).attr('href'),
      title: $(this).attr('alt'),
      img: $('.mfp-container img').attr('data-pin-no-hover', 'true')
    } );
  });
  $.magnificPopup.open({
  type:'image',
  preload: [0,2],
  items:items,
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },

  });
});
```

Anyone knows an solution ?

Answer (score 1):

- `.mfp-container` is available in DOM only after popup is opened.
- Use callbacks, like `change` to access content of current item http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#events

Answer (score 0):

That seems to work. As an reference here my solution

```
/**
* jQuery Magnific Popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)
**/
$('.open-gallery-link').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var items = [];
  $($(this).attr('href')).find('a').each(function() {
  items.push( {
      src: $(this).attr('href'),
      title: $(this).attr('alt')
    } );
  });
  $.magnificPopup.open({
  type:'image',
  preload: [0,2],
    callbacks: {
      change: function() {
       this.content.find('.mfp-img').attr('data-pin-no-hover', 'true')
      },
    },
  items:items,
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
  });
});
```